# Отправка POST-запроса

Tags: post, http

На форме есть два поля (логин/пароль) и кнопка "Войти". Мне надо организовать POST-запрос авторизаии. Пробовал в Fiddler'е скопировать этот запрос, но что-то не выходит. [Вот](http://rosrealt.ru) сайт, для которого это делается. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="login.php">
<label>Login:</label><input type="text" name="data[login]" />
<label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="data[pass]" />
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Вот так отправляется обычный POST запрос.
в login.php получить его можно так:

```
$data=isset($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : null;
```

Comment: А если мне нужна строка, которая просто в адрусную строку браузера вводится?

Comment: тогда это не POST а GET и form method="get" надо

Comment: Вы меня не так поняли. Прошу прощения если я не полностью изложил суть вопроса. У меня есть логин и пароль, мне надо сформировать ссылку для аутентификации. Чтобы я ее вставил в адрусную строку браузера и он меня сразу же переместил в личный кабинет. Порыскал в интернете, нашел пример для mail.tu : http://www.mail.ru/cgi-bin/auth?Login=your_login&Domain=mail.ru&Password=your_password. Мне надо такую же, но для другого сайта.

Comment: ну так а че обработка через $_GET не устраивает? передаете в строке http://your.site/login.php?login=login&pass=password
в login.php достаете $_GET: $login = $_GET['login']; $pass=$_GET['pass'];
И дальше с помощью этих данных авторизируйте пользователя. 
Но это очень скользкий путь, через get передавать имя и пароль...
или я опять не так понял?

Comment: Ну здесь одно из двух: либо я вас, либо вы меня. Скорее всего первое:) Попробовал вот так:
http://rosrealt.ru/rosrealt/myrosrealt.php?Email=МОЙЭМЕЙЛ&Password=МОЙПАРОЛЬ Не срабатывет, хотя после этого поле эмейла остается заполненным.

Comment: Сделал!!!:) Один параметр проглядел. Вот так работает http://rosrealt.ru/rosrealt/myrosrealt.php?act=check&Email=МОЙЭМЕЙЛ&Password=МОЙПАРОЛЬ. Спасибо большое за помощь:)